# Query output values in array

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a lot of trouble understanding why sometimes my queries return values and sometimes it get something else, pointers?

I think there is a concept I'm missing about variables.

```
$sql = "SELECT 
    customerData.studFirstName,
    customerData.studLastName, 
    customerData.custPhone,
    customerData.studPhone, 
    classRoll.courseNumber, 
    classRoll.payFull, 
    classRoll.payAmount
FROM classRoll, customerData
WHERE classRoll.custId = customerData.custId
AND classRoll.courseNumber =  '".$_REQUEST['cnum']."'
ORDER BY customerData.studLastName;";

$result = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM classRoll");
while ($row= $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $output[]=$row[studLastName].", ".$row[studFirstName];
};
var_dump($output);
?>
```

The query works in phpadmin, but I get this

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(2) ", " }
```

I don't want a solution as bad as an understanding. I appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you are getting single value, you don't need to put that in `while loop`.
- secondly 
  `$output[]=$row[studLastName].", ".$row[studFirstName];` these keys are not exist, as you are querying count.
- You are not using `$sql`

You may simply fetch, results and use it, see example below:-

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM classRoll");
$row = $result->fetch_row();
echo $row[0];
```

but, I guess you probably want to you `$sql`, for that code looks fine.

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row= $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $output[]=$row['studLastName'].", ".$row['studFirstName'];
}
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: I've changed so much in here, I missed that. I can't say I understand much better, but that worked. Thanks.

Comment: `$result->fetch_row();` will return array and the index, starts from 0 to number of  columns - 1

`$result->fetch_assoc()` will return array with column names as index.

does this make sense ? I suggest you to go through with [PHP Mannual ](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php)

Comment: I think i get it. I'll keep digging through documentation. It's just a bit heavy.